# Why is it "für ihren Bruder" but not "für ihr Bruder"?

Tags: grammatical-case, possessive-pronoun, nominative

I couldn't figure out the grammar rule here. I know it is possessive pronoun but  I don't know the case (it seems nominative here)

> Sie kauft die blaue Mütze für ihr**en** Bruder.

Please tell me why it is ihr**en** here?

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/f%C3%BCr

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer:**

[für](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/f%C3%BCr) asks for the accusative case, Bruder is singular masculine, so one has to use [ihren](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ihren) there, because this is the accusative masculine singular inflection of ihr.

**Additional comments:**

In general, you should be able to determine the case by searching for the preposition in some dictionary or even on Google.

Actually, knowing the case taken by a preposition is is not complicated at all if you have a good memory (or have practiced enough).

By the way, [this wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/German/Grammar/Prepositions_and_Postpositions) has a decent lesson about prepositions and cases.

Comment: I didn't know before für is an akkusative preposition. Hehe.